# HTML Connect4 Stacking Images

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little problem with my Code. I tried to programm Connect4 as a HTML Website, so i had the idea that i could make this with Javascript so i did this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CONNECT4 Nils Version</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
body {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>CONNECT4 N-Version</h1>
<input type="image" src="normal.png" id="1" width="100" onclick="einsrr()"> 
<input type="image" src="normal.png" id="2" width="100" onclick="zweirr()">
 <input type="image" src="normal.png" id="3" width="100" onclick="dreirr()">
 <input type="image" src="normal.png" id="4" width="100" onclick="vierrr()">
 <input type="image" src="normal.png" id="5" width="100" onclick="fuenfrr()">
 <input type="image" src="normal.png" id="6" width="100" onclick="sechsrr()">
 <input type="image" src="normal.png" id="7" width="100" onclick="siebenrr()"><br>

 <img src="normal.png" id="11" width="100"> 
 <img src="normal.png" id="12" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="13" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="14" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="15" width="100"> 
 <img src="normal.png" id="16" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="17" width="100"><br>

 <img src="normal.png" id="21" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="22" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="23" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="24" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="25" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="26" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="27" width="100"><br>

 <img src="normal.png" id="31" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="32" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="33" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="34" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="35" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="36" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="37" width="100"><br>

 <img src="normal.png" id="41" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="42" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="43" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="44" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="45" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="46" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="47" width="100"><br>

 <img src="normal.png" id="51" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="52" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="53" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="54" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="55" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="56" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="57" width="100"><br>

 <img src="normal.png" id="61" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="62" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="63" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="64" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="65" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="66" width="100">
 <img src="normal.png" id="67" width="100"><br><br><br>
</center>
<script>
function einsrr() {
    if (document.getElementById("61").src = "normal.png") {
        document.getElementById("61").src = "redstone.png";
        }else if(document.getElementById("51").src = "normal.png") {
            document.getElementById("51").src ="redstone.png";  
        }else   if(document.getElementById("41").src = "normal.png") {
            document.getElementById("41").src = "redstone.png";
        }else if(document.getElementById("31").src = "normal.png") {
            document.getElementById("31").src = "redstone.png";
        }else if(document.getElementById("21").src = "normal.png") {
            document.getElementById("21").src = "redstone.png";
        }else if(document.getElementById("11").src = "normal.png") {
            document.getElementById("11").src = "redstone.png";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What i wanted to do is that it checks when you click on the first row if there is the image normal.png if that is true it replaces it with the image redstone.png if it is false it tests for the image above it but i only can click one time on the image when i click another time it wont do anything i would apreciate if someone helps me Thank you :D

Comment: what do you want to achieve? because your code implying that you are new to javascript

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain what you are attempting to accomplish, but for starters, in function einsrr() rather than using the assignment operator "=" in the test clause, it should be the comparison operator "==" or "===" like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("61").src == "http://yourSite.com/path2image/normal.png") { //etc.
```

Note that with .src the entire url must be compared, not just "normal.png"

So, tested good on my server:

```
<script>
    function einsrr() {
        if (document.getElementById("t").src == 'http://yourServer.com/path2images/normal.png') {
            document.getElementById("t").src = 'redstone.png';
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <center>
    <h1>CONNECT4 N-Version3</h1>
    <img src="normal.png" id="t" onclick="einsrr();"> 
    <br><br>
    </center>
```

...works, the images are swapped. But that's a one time swap - You'll need to add to the if else if logic if you want to swap back and forth, etc.

Comment: Are normal and redstone.png in the same directory as your script?

Comment: Yes they are all in the same folder